# Query joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am just starting off using sql databases I have a question about a query which would return results from multiple tables. Sorry if this is really trivial, I've been trying to research it myself but didn't know the appropriate terminology to look for.

I have three tables:

```
Patient -
PatientID*
Surname
FName
DoB
Address
PhoneNo

Doctor -
DoctorID*
Surname
FName
DoB
Address
PhoneNo

Appointment -
AppointmentID*
DoctorID
PatientID
Time
Date
```

I want the query to return all appointments, but replace the DoctorID and PatientID with the matching doctors surname, and patients surname. So returning AppointmentID, doctors Surname, patients Surname, Time and Date.

I hope I have explained this well enough for someone to understand!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a inner join

```
select a.AppointmentID, b.Surname, b.FNAME, c.Surname, c.FName
from Appointment as a
Inner join Doctor as b on b.DoctorID = a.DoctorID
Inner join Patient as c on c.PatientID = a,PatientID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   a.AppointmentID,
   a.Time,
   a.Date,
   d.Surname,
   p.Surname
FROM
   Appointment a with (nolock)
   left join
   Doctor d with (nolock) on
   d.DoctorID = a.DoctorID
   left join
   Patient p with (nolock) on
   p.PatientID = a.PatientID
```

Comment: Why would you use a left join here?  Are you expecting there to be appointments that don't have a corresponding doctor or patient?

Comment: Since he didn't specify, this would ensure that if there were appointments that were scheduled but no physician had been assigned. This can happen in real life--we see it all the time in our 400-bed hospital.